# jquery submit form redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How can I get this to work on submit instead of on click?

Here is my form:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="value" value="http://google.com"><span>Google</span><br>
    <input type="radio" name="value" value="http://yahoo.com"><span>Yahoo</span><br>
    <input type="radio" name="value" value="http://bing.com"><span>Bing</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[name$='value']").click(function() {
         window.location = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: if you want your radios to work as a group the way you are trying to access it, you will need to add them into some kind of group in html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just attach a submit handler to the form

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();//prevent the form from actually submitting
        var $choice = $(this).find("input[name='value']:checked");//get the selected option 
        if ($choice.length)// if an option is selected
            window.location = $choice.val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And another one

```
$('input[value="Submit"]').click(function() {
    var loc = $('form input:radio:checked').val();
    window.location = loc;
    return false;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCVsp/) for testing.